# Passing in a JSON_OBJECT_T into SODA_DOCUMENT_T

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-autonomous-db, oracle-soda

I have a PL/SQL handler using the SODA package to manipulate a JSON database. I want to:

1. Read the value for key `id` in the payload
2. Write the payload JSON into a new document in the database.

To do **step 1**, The handler takes `:body` to be parsed as a JSON_OBJECT_T type, so that I can access the value for key `id` in the payload.

But for **step 2**, if I read `body` again when constructing with `SODA_DOCUMENT_T(b_content=> :body)`, it will simply give me a blank document.

I also can't pass in the JSON_OBJECT_T variable in directly, like `SODA_DOCUMENT_T(j_content=> jso)`, because that function expects a JSON type and not a JSON_OBJECT_T. I can't find the JSON type documentation, but saw in code examples the function `JSON('{}')` to generate one.

Reading `:body_text` however gives me other problems - because `JSON()` function cannot handle line breaks in the payload and gives an error instead.

**Currently** to work around this I'm using the following:

```
SODA_DOCUMENT_T(
  j_content => JSON(jso.to_string())
)
```

Which seems very silly because I'm serialising it to a string again before converting it back into JSON type. Is there a proper way to read the value of a key of the payload, and pass it into the SODA_DOCUMENT_T?

Comment: Hope the answer helped, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  you can't pass in `JSON_Object_T` instance to `SODA_Document_T` constructor. However, you may use `JSON_QUERY()` PL/SQL function that drills into the JSON document given a path expression and it returns a JSON type instance.

**Example:**

```
jval := JSON_QUERY(body, '$.id' RETURNING JSON);
```

In the above example, `$.id` is the path expression and `json_query()` returns json value corresponding to the field `id` starting from the root `$`

Documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/function-JSON_QUERY.html

You should now be able to pass this `jval` instance of type `JSON` to `SODA_Document_T` constructor.

Yes, I think you should definitely avoid back and forth conversions.

**Usage:**

```
SQL> 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_request(body  IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN JSON
IS
  j  JSON;
  d  SODA_Document_T;
BEGIN
  
  j := JSON_QUERY(body, '$.id' RETURNING JSON);
  d := SODA_Document_T(j_Content => j);
  -- n := coll.insert_one(d);
  RETURN j;
END;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT process_request('{"id":{"type": "string", "val": "DEADBEEF"}}') FROM dual;

PROCESS_REQUEST('{"ID":{"TYPE":"STRING","VAL":"DEADBEEF"}}')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"type":"string","val":"DEADBEEF"}
```

I recommend this approach. Let me know if that helps!

**Alternate solution:**

BTW, given a DOM, you can directly go to JSON type instance as well, using the following method in `JSON_Object_T` type:

```
MEMBER FUNCTION GET_JSON RETURNS JSON
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 KEY                            VARCHAR2                IN
```

This method pretty much does the same work as `JSON_Query()` shown above:

```
SQL>
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_body(data IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN JSON
AS
  body JSON_Object_T;
  j    JSON;
BEGIN
  body := JSON_Object_T.parse(data);
  j := body.get_Json('id');
  return j;
END;
 11  /

SQL> SELECT process_body('{"id":{"type": "string", "val": "DEADBEEF"}}') FROM dual;

PROCESS_BODY('{"ID":{"TYPE":"STRING","VAL":"DEADBEEF"}}')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"type":"string","val":"DEADBEEF"}
```